# How to get recent participants in my android app?

Tags: java, android, jitsi-meet, lib-jitsi-meet

I am using jitsi meet sdk for *video conferencing app*. But i can't get they **recent participant or history.**
In original jitsi meet android app had recent option. I don't know how to get that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to could that in code, but here is a way to do it:

1. Create A File and name it the current time
2. Create a window for choosing what time the participants were present using Java swing. (a menu) with a help of a button.
3. Print All The Participants Using A loop to the file
4. Link each menu item to the file with the text name of the file without file  extension.
5. Keep Doing All This Steps (1-4)in A Loop until the meeting ends.

For more ideas, get some reference from other Apps like Google Meet
and Zoom.

Comment: Thank you for your respectable comment. but i can't get all of participant.

Comment: Learn Debugging. its is a critical skill to learn